# Capacitor replacement on ancient Fisher & Pykel fridge - which pins to connect?

Tags: repair

[image: phase lines]I have three pins on this compressor:
[a] white wire post - live phase - bottom left
[b] capacitor resister - copper terminal - top left
[c[ black wire post - ground to wall - bottom right

It's so old it's probably one of the first ever made: ABE021 is the serial.

When completely cool - meaning the compressor is unplugged and not running, cold to the touch - the fridge will start first time nicely, and run well for 10 minutes.

I reckon the start capacitor is blown, and when the thermo-resister (shown as capsule shaped copper in pics) is preventing the cap or start coil from getting enough juice for a 2nd re-start. Instead I can hear the relay clicking back in place due to lack of rotation energy, but i can hear the compressor spin still.

I plan to connect a new capacitor to one of the three options, with impedances:
a/b - 70 ohms (relay???) 
a/c - 27 ohms (run coil?)
b/c - 42 ohms (from capacitor to ground) <---- current choice to add new cap.

[image: shot of resistor]
[image: NS4/14]
[image: model KS400 and very early serial: 00ABE020 I would say if there was someone there called ABE, then this serial is even earlier than might first seem!]
[image: Kelvinator]

Model ZS4/14 and E00 BBA 023
Model KS400 and very early serial: E00 ABE 020

I would say if there was someone there called ABE, then this serial is even earlier than might first seem!

Comment: The brass strap is shorting out a cap symbol.  I have no idea why BUT removing the strap and adding a cap instead is unlikely to do any harm. Unlikely :-). | Are you in New Zealand? - if so, have you asked F&P?

Comment: Looks at profile. Yep. NZ :-)

Comment: What is the model number? This probably won't help 
https://www.fisherpaykel.com/common/download/support/FP-Serial-Number-Locations.pdf